# <script> tags inside Underscore.js templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

I'm having trouble getting nested JavaScript inside Underscore templates to run.

```
<script type="text/template" id="myTemplate">
   <h3><%= heading %></h3>
   <div class="container"></div>

   //THIS DOES NOT WORK --->
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(".container").html("Test")
   </script>
   //END

</script>
```

Is this at all possible or how could I work around the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: `&lt;script> ..... </script&gt;` perhaps?

Comment: The whole point of using templates is so that you don't need to manually call scripts. You can't do it, and you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript certainly doesn't belong into a template. So it only makes sense that they do not work.

If you need to execute scripts related to the template, put them in a function and call them when you render the template.

Answer (score 22):

```
<script type="text/template" id="myTemplate">
   <h3><%= heading %></h3>
   <div class="container"></div>

   //THIS WORK :) --->

   <% print("<sc" + "ript type='text/javascript'>"); %>

     $(".container").html("Test")

    <% print("</sc"+"ript>"); %>

   //END

</script>
```

I had to do so, because I had to generate an unknown number of functions.

Comment: Or you are generating html to be executed in a different context.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method for templating an html page.

```
<script type="text/template" id="mypage">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"><%= "<"+"/script>" %>
    </body>
  </html>
</script>
```